# Virtual Earth Control - strange floating behavior

Tags: hover, virtual-earth

I've been working my way through the ["NerdDinner" MVC tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx), and I just reached the part about adding a map control. 
I've run into some strange behavior of the Virtual Earth control that I just can't seem to figure out:

http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/3379/virtualearth.png

If you can't see the picture, the Virtual Earth control is floating in the top-left corner, obscuring the form, separated from the containing div, which isn't really in the correct position either, but it's better than where the control is.

As far as I can tell, I've copied all related code directly from the tutorial. Has anyone seen something like this before?

I'm using Firefox for most of my testing, but it appears to behave the same way in Internet Explorer 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it would appear that the tutorial requires some CSS that it doesn't tell you about :/
Was able to retrieve it from the official "finished product" source code.

Comment: It would be useful to know what the CSS lines which were important.  I have come across strange behavior with the map and controls also.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me crazy!

The missing CSS is:

```
#theMap {
    position: relative; 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 450px;
}
```